# How to format date and time in CRON format in php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I have a Date and Time in this format **11-28-2013 10:52:16** (this is my frontend timestamp) using a small JS script i can select any thing here, i have to convert it into like **2013-11-28 10:52:16** (this is mysql timestamp)

I want PHP to format timestamp for MySQL

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Using my JS i can enter dynamic time and date ....

Comment: What has this to do with `cron` or PHP?

Comment: that JS also possible with Cron job in PHP (i just found it in internet)

Comment: This has no relation to cron job

Comment: Are you talking about node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this

```
<?php
$datefromJS="11-28-2013 10:52:16";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s',$datefromJS); 
echo $mysqlformat=$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
2013-11-28 10:52:16
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use somthing like the following

```
<?php
$old_date_timestamp = strtotime('11-28-2013 10:52:16');
$new_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $old_date_timestamp);  
?>
```